# R Error: time-series/vector length mismatch

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
weeks <- rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2023-01-01"), by = "week"), each = 1)
counts <- rpois(length(weeks), lambda = 50)
df <- data.frame(Week = as.character(weeks), Count = counts)
```

I am trying to fit a time series model to this data and perform LOOCV (Leave One Out Cross Validation). That is:

- I want to fit a model to 70% of the data (in chronological order)
- Predict the next point (horizon = 1)
- Record the error of this prediction
- Predict the next point, record the error
- Repeat until the remaining 30% has been completed - record the final average error (RMSE, MAE)

Using this post as a reference (http://freerangestats.info/blog/2019/07/20/time-series-cv), I tried to write a loop to perform this procedure.

First, I set up the requirements for the loop:

```
# Split data into training and test sets
train_size <- floor(0.7 * nrow(df))
train <- df[1:train_size, ]
test <- df[(train_size + 1):nrow(df), ]

# Fit ARIMA model to training data
model <- auto.arima(train$Count)

# Initialize vector to store prediction errors
errors <- vector("numeric", length = nrow(test))

rmse_vec <- numeric()
mae_vec <- numeric()
```

Next, I tried to run the loop:

```
# Loop over test set
for (i in seq(train_end+1, n)) {
    
    # Split data into training and validation sets
    train <- df[1:(i-1), ]
    val <- df[i:(i+1), ]
    
    # Fit ARIMA model to training data
    model <- auto.arima(train$Count)
    
    # Forecast one step ahead using the model and record error
    fc <- forecast(model, h = 1)
    error <- val$Count - fc$mean
    
    # Record RMSE and MAE
    rmse_vec[i - train_end - 1] <- sqrt(mean(error^2))
    mae_vec[i - train_end - 1] <- mean(abs(error))
    
    # Update training data with actual count
    train$Count <- c(train$Count, val$Count[1])
}

# Compute mean RMSE and MAE
mean_rmse <- mean(rmse_vec)
mean_mae <- mean(mae_vec)
```

**Problem:** However, this code is giving me the following error:

```
 Error in `-.default`(val$Count, fc$mean) : 
  time-series/vector length mismatch
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this? **Am I doing LOOCV for time series models correctly?**

Thanks!

- **Note** : I am not sure if this is how LOOCV is typically performed on time series models - perhaps someone here knows?

Comment: what is train_end ? it is never initiated in your code above

Comment: @ BPeif: Thank you for your reply! I am still working on this problem - in general, have I done this LOOCV procedure correctly?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the right approach it is to train the model with the training set, test the performance with the first value (LVO) or batch (CV), shift the data to include in the train set this already used test data, next iteration (train, test, shift, ...). If that's your for loop, your approach is right. To know more: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection , https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-correctly-perform-cross-validation-for-time-series-b083b869e42c

Comment: @RobertoT: thank you for your answer! do you know how to write this in R?